# GNU grub instead of grub 2

Tags: boot, grub2, gnu-screen, gnu, kali

I recently uninstalled kali Linux from a triple boot laptop (othres being windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04) now instead of grub 2 which shows windows and ubuntu during booting all I can see is a GNU grub which I have no idea what to do , when I enter 'exit' I go to windows and can't enter ubuntu ,how can I get back grub 2 , please help

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  You may just need to reinstall Ubuntu's grub. If knowledgeable, you may actually only need to edit /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to have correct UUID & partition for Ubuntu. If not, just do a total reinstall of grub (not update only) from advanced options in Boot-Repair.

Comment: How to use ppa version ,

Comment: Boot Ubuntu live installer in same boot mode as installs, probalby UEFI and use ppa to add Boot-Repair. Click on box that says run BootInfo Summary Report. Copy & paste link into your question above. Advanced options button has more detail here, showing menus you get. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I now booted in to kali Linux and I think I deleted the ubuntu partition instead of kali Linux ,and I am going to install Ubuntu again and then I can get my grub 2 which shows all the three boot OS ubuntu,kali and windows ,am I right

Comment: Always use Linux tools for Linux and Windows tools for Linux. From Windows you cannot correctly see Linux partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/
above link has detailed information on how to fix the issue
And if you have any problems while trying the Linux line command in the above link,enter exit and the restart you PC or laptop then enter BIOS settings (F10) disable secure boot , save the settings and go back to GNU grub and do as in the above link ,it will go like a pro

Answer (score 0):

Backup your data, boot into Ubuntu, delete the Kali partition, using GParted or other partitioning software, run sudo update-grub and reboot

Comment: I deleted kali partition from windows disk management , after that I am not able to get in to ubuntu

Comment: there is a thread that may help- https://superuser.com/questions/227525/remove-os-from-linux-dual-boot/227552#227552

Comment: To do it I have to boot in to ubuntu which I am not able to do